# Background music with .mp3 file plays late

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use cocos2d-x RC1 and I need a background music to play from an mp3 file. The problem is that it starts to play after 2-3 seconds. I have tried to preload it but here is the problem:

```
void SimpleAudioEngine::preloadBackgroundMusic(const char* pszFilePath)
{
}
```

`SimpleAudioEngine::preloadBackgroundMusic` is a dummy function and does nothing. Also there is no callback that tells that background music is loaded, so that I could show loading screen untill that moment. Now I don't know how to control the time the music will start to play.

Another was is the .wav file that plays immediately, but .wav file size is 49Mb, which is nonsense. Thus, I stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on the Cocos2d forums about filing a bug for this.

Also, please try and reproduce this in the latest final release: http://cocos2d-x.org/download